# behavior with "require-session-token = true" and "require-authentication="anonymous-all" attribute defined when making Restful post call

Tags: moqui

when the post Restful call(neither api_key given nor authentication info given in HTTP header) send to the server on which both "require-session-token = true"  and  "require-authentication='anonymous-all' "  attributes are defined, Moqui gives ' Session token required (in moquiSessionToken) ...' message. Is this behavior designed in purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As no one answer this questions, I suppose it is the designed in purpose. Though you do post RESTful call which should be stateless on the server, you will have to provide the api_key or authtenticaiton information in the http request in order to get rid of the ' Session token required (in moquiSessionToken) ...' message.